# In C# how can I get names of files from a checkListBox and move the files?

Tags: c#, file, checklistbox

In C# I need to know how I can use item names in a `checkListBox` as file paths so a user can select the file names then click a button that will move those files to another file location on the pc. I already know how to get the files to appear in the `checkListBox` but I do not know how to detect file paths in the `checkListBox` so a user can move the selected files listed in the `checkListBox`.

If it helps, this is a better way of saying it. I want to get the listed files in a list box, and do something with them.

```
void sendbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string destinationFolder = gamedir.Text;
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(checkListView1.SelectedItems);
            foreach(var file in files)
            {
                string destinationPath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file);
                File.Copy(file.Fullname, destinationPath);
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post some code? That is always helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.IO.Directory`

- Directory List :

  `Directory.GetDirectories`
- File List under the directory

  `Directory.GetFiles("Path");`
- File full path :

  `System.IO.Path.GetFileName`
- Move File

  `Directory.Move`

Answer (score 0):

Create struct which contains file path and optionaly file name to shorten items in ComboBox:

```
struct ComboItem {
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return FileName;
    }
}
```

Overriding ToString() do the magic - in ComboBox you will see only file names. Populate ComboBox like this:

```
void FillCombo() {
    var startPath = @"your path";
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(startPath)) {
        var item = new ComboItem {
            FilePath = file,
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(file)
        };
        comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And than on move action get selected item:

```
var item = (ComboItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

In item you have file name and file path.